# Issues when Statically Compiling SDL2 program

Tags: c, sdl, static-libraries, sdl-2

I'm working on a simple Hello World type program using C and SDL2 on a Windows platform (gcc compiler on Cygwin, running on Windows 7).

My program compiles fine and runs fine as long as I'm compiling with the dynamically linked libraries, and that the SDL2.dll file is in the same directory as my running program.

However, when I add the '-static' compiler flag to gcc line when compiling, I get a ton of "undefined reference" errors such as this:

```
undefined reference to `_imp__waveInAddBuffer@12'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what the problem is here?

EDIT: I forgot to specify that I'm using MinGW as my compiler toolchain.

EDIT: I'm including the gcc compiler flag that worked (taken from the accepted answer below, plus a few additions from myself):

```
-Wl,-Bstatic -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -Wl,-Bdynamic -lws2_32 -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinm m -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lversion -luuid -lcomdlg32 -lhid -lsetupapi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question appears to be windows-specific, things may (or not) be different on other systems, although some things are very much alike.

I don't think you can ever produce executable with cygwin without `cygwin1.dll` dependency.

`-static` prevents linker from ever considering any dynamic library, not just SDL. There are many dlls that are part of windows installation (so you can expect them to be present on target system) but they don't have static version, and if any of your program's code uses them (be it your code or, in that case, SDL), you can't produce executable with `-static` here. You can use static versions of some libraries though, e.g. SDL - that will require having corresponding `.a` (or `.lib` for MSVC), *and* specifying all dependencies said library have (as `.a` don't have dependency information built into it, while dynamic libraries do), e.g. for SDL2 it could be something like

```
-Wl,-Bstatic SDL2main SDL2 -Wl,-Bdynamic -lws2_32 -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lversion -luuid -lcomdlg32
```

(`-Bstatic` asks linker to use static verions of libraries that comes after that; `-Bdynamic` is reverse; `-Wl,...` passes option to linker)

If using mingw, you may also want `--static-libgcc` and `--static-libstdc++` (and not depending on cygwin dll as an added bonus).

Comment: Thanks, yes I am using MinGW (I added this to my post for clarity). I added -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++ to the gcc compile line, but I'm still getting the same errors, like the following: ../../dev_libraries/windows/lib\libSDL2.a(SDL_windows.o): In function `WIN_CoInitialize':
/Users/valve/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.9-source/foo-x86/../src/core/windows/SDL_windows.c:76: undefined reference to `_imp__CoInitializeEx@8'

Comment: said function should be in `ole32`; do you have it in your linking command? Is it specified after SDL2? Basically for each function you have to search MSDN for library name and link with it. However my answer already have ole32 and many others that you'll probably need.

Comment: Success! I had to add a couple more libraries to the ones you suggested but I eventually got there. The .exe file is now about 40 times bigger than the dynamically linked version, and it runs WITHOUT the SDL2.dll file being available! Here is my full gcc option I used to statically link:   WINDOWS_STATIC_COMPILER_FLAGS = -Wl,-Bstatic -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -Wl,-Bdynamic -lws2_32 -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinm    m -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lversion -luuid -lcomdlg32 -lhid -lsetupapi

Comment: I had no idea a C program that uses SDL2 depends on so many other dynamically linked libraries to run. But I guess its safe to assume that all these libraries will be available on any Windows 7 machine?

Comment: Yes, I think all of these are available starting with windows xp (at least with its latest service pack).